# PHP: getallheaders() not working in mail()?

Tags: php, http, header

I am trying to do something like:

```
<?php
// Defining function getallheaders() as it is disabled on my host
    function getallheaders() 
    { 
           $headers = ''; 
       foreach ($_SERVER as $name => $value) 
       { 
           if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'HTTP_') 
           { 
               $headers[str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', substr($name, 5)))))] = $value; 
           } 
       } 
       return $headers;
}

$getheader=getallheaders();

mail("me@domain.com","mail","Headers: \n $getheader");
?>
```

It sends me a mail like:

```
Headers: Array(
```

Why doesn't it mail all the headers? Thx in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created `$heareds` variable as an array.

Instead of:

```
$headers[str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', substr($name, 5)))))] = $value;
```

Use this:

```
$headers .= str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', substr($name, 5))))) .': ' . $value . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Where does `$heareds` come from?

Comment: It's output is "NULL"

Comment: I forgot newlines. What output is null?

Comment: I don't think my script was wrong if I created that as an array cuz when I executed the script in browser it showed me my headers but sent only first 6 characters of headers " Array(" to my mail.

And when I tried yours and executed on browser, I got "NULL" (yes, null was written).

Comment: You must have a typo somewhere. `$headers` is initiated as empty string, can't be null.